# Python to write different column values as row values to excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, vba

I have an excel with multiple columns and rows. I am trying to read each row and write the values of certain select columns as row values. For example :

This is the excel I am reading in:
[image: input]

I am trying to get the output as csv or excel:

[image: output]

I have tried to loop through and write each at a time but it does not work:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
     df[['UNIQUE_ID']].to_excel('U:/IMAT/test3.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1', header=None, index=False,
             startcol=1,startrow=i)
i+=1
df[['SENDING_FACILITY']].to_excel('U:/IMAT/test3.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1', header=None, index=False,
             startcol=1,startrow=i)
i+=1
```

This does not seem to work and only writes the second statement. Thank you for any help !!

Comment: please provide your input/output data as **text**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df_new=pd.DataFrame(columns=["col_1","col_2"])
for i,j in df.iterrows():
    df_new=df_new.append({"col_1":j["UNIQUE_ID"]},ignore_index=True)
    df_new=df_new.append({"col_1":j["SENDING_FACILITY"],"col_2":j["SENDING_CODE"]},ignore_index=True)
df_new.to_excel('U:/IMAT/test3.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1', header=None, index=False)
```